# Java font locations

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, gradle, fonts

[Java supports true type physical fonts, and looks for font files in the JRE fonts library, and then from the font location(s) defined by the host operating system](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/font.html). On OSX I have an arial.ttf (from windows) located in $JAVA_HOME/lib/fonts/, I have removed the mac Arial.ttf from /Library/Fonts, and there no arial font files in any of the [other font locations](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201722).

When I start a Java SE 6 application from IntelliJ (and confirm the System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") is set to my $JAVA_HOME), the
`GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames()` and `getAllFonts()` do not list "Arial", even after an "Invalidate Caches and Restart". When I run the same application in a terminal, the System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") reports the same location but "Arial" is listed as an available font family (and I can use the arial font in my application).

- In the terminal `java version "1.6.0_65"` and `javac 1.6.0_65`, and `which java` gives me my `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java`. `JAVA_HOME` points to a JDK, not a JRE.
- In IntelliJ the project SDK is set to the same 1.6.0_65 JDK, and the project language level is 6.
- In both cases I am launching from gradle, where I have specified `sourceCompatibility = 1.6`.
- `-Djava.awt.headless` is not set in either case.

Any suggestions as to why the arial font is not being found when the application is launched from IntelliJ?

---

Edit: I tried some more things:

- Added Arial Black.ttf to the JRE dir, this was also only detected when launched from the terminal.
- When both arial.ttf and Arial Black.ttf were moved from the JRE fonts dir to the /Library/Fonts, both the terminal and IntelliJ pick up the arial black font, but now neither see the arial font.
- Switching to a java 8 compiler, JDK, JAVA_HOME, project language level, and source compatibility, yields the same results with the arial font only being visible from the terminal.

Comment: Have you considered [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/fontconfig.html) article? More specifically, the _Appended Font Path_ topic.

Comment: Thanks. Adding a new font path had no effect, even manually loading the font in java did not work which leads me towards suspecting some sort of conflict with a system font.

Comment: Is $JAVA_HOME set to your jdk or jre?  I'm guessing the jdk.  Try putting the fonts into $JRE_HOME/lib/fonts.  Just a guess.